# Scheme Parameter Not Applicable

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, scheme, mit-scheme

I am starting to learn Scheme and well, I am trying to implement my own max function that gives the max of just two parameters.

I've written the function like this:
`(define (myMax x y) (cond ((> x y) (x)) ((< x y) (y))))`

But every time I try calling it `(myMax 100 40)`(example) I get an error that says:
`The object 100 is not applicable.`

Searching the documentation of GNU's MIT-Scheme, they say:
`This type indicates an error in which a program attempted to apply an object that is not a procedure. The object being applied is saved in the datum field, and the arguments being passed to the object are saved as a list in the operands field.` 
But what is that supposed to mean?

Weird thing is, I implemented a very simple function that adds two numbers and it works just fine, also an absolute value function that works fine; could it be the conditional is messed up?

Thanks

Comment: What should happen when `x` is equal to `y`? Maybe an `if` is more appropriate.

Comment: You're right, I tried to ignore it just to get the thing working.
But why would `if` be more appropriate? I can just add another condition; is there any reason why that's less appropriate?

Comment: It has one condition instead of two: `(if (> x y) x y)`

Comment: You could use `(cond ((> x y) x) ((<= x y) y))` or `(cond ((> x y) x) (else y))`, but the `if` looks nicer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Scheme `(function-name arguments)` is the syntax for applying a function to the given arguments. So `(x)` means "apply the function `x` to no arguments". However `x` is not a function, which the compiler is trying to tell you by saying that it's not "applicable".

Since you don't actually want to apply `x`, simply remove the parentheses around it. Same for `(y)` in the other case of the `cond`.

Comment: emmm a question;
doesn't (x) evaulate to x? or am I mixing data and functions here?

Comment: @AdelQodmani `(x)` evaluates to the result of calling `x` without arguments if `x` is a function and to an error otherwise.